# Magento 2 - Move header links to side of mini cart

Tags: magento2, layout, luma-theme

I am trying to move the top content of the header panel to by the minicart:

[image]

I have tried several methods such as:

```
<move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="minicart"/>
```

I have also tried creating a custom block and adding them to that:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <container name="custom_header" as="custom_header" label="My Custom Header" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-header" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>

<move element="header.panel" as="header.panel" destination="custom_header"/>

<move element="header.links" destination="custom_header" before="-"/>
<move element="currency" destination="custom_header" after="header.links"/>
```

But when they move they lose their dropdown formatting:
[image]

Anyone know how I can achieve this on the Luma theme.
Magento 2.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These elements in panel header need the class **panel header** to show correctly, thats'why you lost the format when you moved the block.

An option would be to move logo, search and minicart in the *header.panel* container then adjust the css.

```
<move element="logo" destination="header.panel" before="-"/>
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel"/>
<move element="minicart" destination="header.panel"/>
```

Comment: What a great suggestion! Works a treat :-) Thank you